# WxPython - Binding an Event to a Randomly changing value - Algorithm Required

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a textBox on my WxPython GUI, where I am displaying a changing value (Which changes every 100 mS). I have two buttons - Button A, Button B.

Initial condition: Textbox has a value of between 2000-3000. Button A is enabled, Button B is disabled.

I need the following sequence of events to go on:
The user presses the Button A. After approximately 20 seconds or some user defined time (completely variable based on the user/ type of work he is doing), the textBox value goes under less 50.

Once the textBox value goes less than 50 - Button B should be enabled.

Currently this is my following code, where I am pressing the Button A - waiting for the textBox value to less than 50. Then enable the Button B - and it is not working. The button B is not getting enabled. I tried using other means, but they are leaving to an unresponsive GUI. My Button A is - DONE, Button B is START. textBox is pressure_text_control.

```
def OnDone(self, event):
    self.WriteToController([0x04],'GuiMsgIn')
    self.status_text.SetLabel('PRESSURE CALIBRATION DONE \n DUMP PRESSURE')
    self.led1.SetBackgroundColour('GREY')
    self.add_pressure.Disable()
    while self.pressure_text_control.GetValue() < 50:
        wx.CallAfter(self.StartEnable, 'Enabling start button')
        #self.start.Enable()

def StartEnable(self):
    self.start.Enable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied sufficient code to be able to see what is going on.
We don't know for example if `self.pressure_text_control.GetValue() < 50` is in fact less than 50, given that you say the value is changing every 100mS.

If your issue is really about the fact that the GUI becomes unresponsive, then investigate `wx.Timer()`
See:
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

The Timer class allows you to execute code at specified intervals, which allows you to process one or more periodic events (you can declare multiple `timers`), as long as they are not long or blocking processes, yet leave the GUI responsive.

mocked up as follows:

```
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.check, self.timer)

def StartmyButton(self):
    self.start.Enable()
    self.timer.Start(100)

def check(self, event):
    "check you input here and process any results"
```

Comment: The self.pressure_text_control.GetValue is a variable I defined in my code, which relates to a text box. The value in the text box is driven by an Embedded processor, which gives value every 100mS. So, my process should check continuously what the value in the text box is and if the value is less than 50, the enable the button. It has to do this, without blocking the GUI. When I click button A - it should start checking the textbox value  continuously (non blocking GUI) if the value goes less than 50, enable button B.

Comment: Thats all the code I have related to the GUI and buttons, the value of self.pressure_text_control.GetValue as I mentioned comes from MCU and pasting that could would not help this question, as it is completely outside into embedded C programming.